# Sort categories in layered navigation alphabitically

Tags: magento-1.8, category, layered-navigation, sorting

We are trying to sort the categories in the layered navigation alphabetically but it is not getting sort.

Tried the following modifications directly in core file at line number 122 for testing purpose.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php
asort($this->_items);
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

please check this way ,it may give you the desired result

get all the categories and run the following loop

```
foreach ($_categories as $_category){ <br>
          $categories[$_category->getName()] = $_category->getUrl();<br>
          ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);<br>
        }
```

hope it solves your problem.